# Changing SQL DB Default values

Tags: sql-server

I have an automatic setup that loads logs from another server locally, where they are being processed into SQL Server Cubes. Every month I automatically create a new Database for the data, so perf isn't impacted and it makes queries and working with it easier.
My problem is that every month I have to open the new DBs (about 9 of them) and manually change the MAX Size for the DB, since the Default value of 5GB is being hit after just a couple days of data.

I want to change the Default MaxSize value, so that new auto-created DBs don't get stuck in processing with the 5GB limit.
I am not able to find any information anywhere on how to do this change?! Is it a registry, a hidden setting in SQL Server, no idea...

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what the `Model` database is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you create the databse?

Look Here: [MSDN: Create Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx)

You can use the `MAXSIZE` parameter.

Comment: Ahhgreat! MAXSIZE parameter is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to assist, please mark as answer if this suits your needs. :)

Comment: already did, and upvoted, but apparently my standing reputation isn't enough to be allowed to do it... ?

Comment: no problem, you can only up vote from 15 rep, but the accepted answer is great, thank you.